# How to change markdown fenced block language

Tags: perl, awk, sed, markdown

I have a lot of code blocks without any language indication in a markdown file, something like:

````
```
ls -l
#any other code goes here ...
```
````

Would any one tell me how to use `sed`, or `awk` or `perl` to append the block indication, for example, `bash`:

````
```bash
ls -l
#any other code goes here ...
```
````

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, we do encourage people on SO to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly add them in code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

````
sed '/^```/{s//&bash/;:a;n;//!ba}' file
````

Look for ```` ``` ```` and append `bash` then continue reading/printing the file until a further occurrence of ```` ``` ````.

Answer (score 2):

If every code fence in your file starts and ends with ```` ``` ```` alone on a line, `awk` seems like a reasonable tool for this.

The following Awk script will append the `lang` variable to every other line that contains only ```` ``` ```` (use `awk -v lang=LANGUAGE` to set the variable easily).

````
{
  if ($0 ~ /^```$/) {  # match lines containing only ```
    fences += 1; # count lines
    print $0 (fences % 2 ? lang : ""); # add lang to even lines
  } else {
    print $0;
  }
}
````

Here it is inlined for use on the command line:

````sh
awk -v lang="$LANGUAGE" \
  '{if($0~/^```$/){c++;print $0(c%2?lang:"")}else{print $0}}' \
  "$FILE"
````

With a little effort, you should be able to adapt this script to skip over existing language tags and deal with things like indented code blocks, if you need those features.

Comment: It worked on my (relatively simple) test file. I added a shell script version to my answer; does that work?

Comment: It is strange that it does not work on `cygwin`. But it indeed works under Linux.  Many thanks again.

Comment: That script is portable to any awk. If it didn't work for you on cygwin then either you copy/pasted wrong or your input file is different. Since all you said was `it does not work` (the worst possible statement of any problem as it provides no information towards identifying and fixing the problem) it's impossible to guess further at what the issue might be.

Comment: @jirassimok and @Ed Morton: @jiassimok's code works fine for `Linux`, `git-bah` and `msys2`. I have no idea why it does not for `cygwin`. Maybe my installation of `cygwin` has problem. Anyway thank you both for your kind answer.

Answer (score 1):

````
$ awk '/```/ && (++c)%2{$0=$0"bash"} 1' file
```bash
ls -l
...
```
````

Change:

````
/```/
````

to:

```
/'''/
```

if appropriate.